# angular scope method override

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have Angular Controller inside controller (nested controllers).
How can i override a method in the parent controller so it will call child method.
For example, in the below example, i want isShow method to call isOK method which is in the 2nd controller (InsideCtrl)

```
var angularApp = angular.module('ManagerApp', []);

angularApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.states = ["NY", "CA", "WA"];
    $scope.isShow=function()
    {
    return $scope.isOK();
    }

    $scope.isOK=function()
    {
    return false;
    }

}]);

angularApp.controller('InsideCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.states2 = ["NY", "CA", "WA"];

    $scope.isOK=function()
    {
    return true;
    }
}]);
```

How can i do it?

Comment: It's a bad practice when your parent scope knows about child scope. Don't use it so.

Comment: What do you mean the parent scope knows about the child scope? And how should i use it?

Comment: If the behaviour of `isOK` in the `InsideCtrl` is reusable (both `InsideCtrl` and `MainCtrl` use it), maybe you can refactor it and put it on a service.

Answer (score 0):

It's bad design when your parent scope depends on child scope and knows about any properties or methods.
I would prefer solution like this (but it's not ideal :) ):

```
var angularApp = angular.module('ManagerApp', []);

angularApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'defaultStateService', function ($scope, defaultStateService) {
    this.stateService = defaultStateService;

    $scope.states = ["NY", "CA", "WA"];
    $scope.isShow=function(state) {
        return stateService.isOK(state);
    }
}]);

angularApp.controller('InsideCtrl', ['$scope', 'customStateService', function ($scope, customStateService) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.states2 = ["NY", "CA", "WA"];
    $scope.$parent.stateService = customStateService;
}]);
```

In this case `ParentController` will work even without `ChildController` if you implement two services: `defaultStateService` and `customStateService` with `isOK` method.

Comment: right, but in my code, parentController works without ChildController as well. It has the isOK method as well...I just want the childController to have isOK method that will override parent's method. Or this is not a correct way to do it?

Comment: It would be better if child controller access to parent because it always has just one parent. Otherwise parentController can have several childs. And your code works fine because you didn't override by child yet. Sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `factory` or `service`to achieve this requirement. These can be used to share a method, variables or values among several controllers.

**HTML & CONTROLLERS**

```js
var angularApp = angular.module('ManagerApp', []);

angularApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'fact', function ($scope, fact) {

    $scope.states = ["NY", "CA", "WA"];
    $scope.isShow=function()
    {
      fact.isOK();
    }

    $scope.isOK=function()
    {
    return false;
    }

}]);

angularApp.factory('fact', function(){
  var obj = {};
obj.isOK = function(){
    alert("LOGIN");
  }
return obj;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ManagerApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<button ng-click="isShow()">Click me</button>
  </div>
```